# Is there an open source spider/crawler that supports build-in javascript execution

Tags: java, javascript, python, open-source, web-crawler

Nowadays most of web pages contain javascript, but I don't find any open source spider that supports build-in javascript execution.

Is there such one crawler?

Comment: [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.htmlf)

Comment: You can hook Selenium or Ghost.py into Scrapy pretty easily.

Comment: Cool, Ghost.py is interesting, I'll dig into it, thanks for the good answer.