# Scrapy: load 'ready-ed' DOM instead of Source

Tags: jquery, dom, scrapy

Page Source

```
<html>
<title>Example Web</title>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('output').value = "Hi There""
}
)

</script>

<body>
<div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As expected, Page Dom when loaded will be:

```
<html>
<title>Example Web</title>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('output').value = "Hi There"
}
)

</script>

<body>
<div id='output'>Hi There</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that when crawling sites using Scrapy, the response is the Page Source, rather than Page DOM. How do I make scrapy to request for Page DOM so that i can extract the 'Hi There' string in the body?

Comment: Perhaps use something like phantomjs instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** make Scrapy to request for Page DOM instead of Page Source **because Scrapy is not a browser**. So, it cannot render Javascript. It simply builds an Element Tree from the response it gets.

Refer [**Google Group discussion on Scrapy supporting Javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870247/is-there-an-open-source-spider-crawler-that-supports-build-in-javascript-executi)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870247/is-there-an-open-source-spider-crawler-that-supports-build-in-javascript-executi): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/tOVH-X7H3DI and [Another StackOverflow discussion on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870247/is-there-an-open-source-spider-crawler-that-supports-build-in-javascript-executi)

But, you might consider using an external [**ScrapyJS MiddleWare**](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) by [ScrapingHub](http://scrapinghub.com/about).